# How does one query a field value in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, idioms

I have code that is at present accessing a React component directly, and getting a warning saying "You probably don't want to do this." The code is:

```
var description = document.getElementById('description').value;
console.log(description);
new_child.setState({
    description: description
});
```

The component it's trying to access is:

```
var that = this;
return (
    <table>
        <tbody>
            {that.state.children}
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <td>
                <textarea className="description"
                          placeholder=" Your next task..."
                          onChange={that.onChange} 
                          name="description"
                          id="description"></textarea><br />
                <button onClick={that.handleClick}
                        id="save-todo">Save</button>
            </td>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
    );
```

What is an idiomatic way to replace the code I have here with a "thinking in React" replacement?

Comment: Where is the first code block running in? Is it inside a component's `render` method?

Comment: The first code is in a handleClick() method. The second is in the render() method itself. I suspect I'm doing something the framework wants to do.

Comment: can you post your full component instead of snippets (with the irrelevant bits trimmed off, of course)? That'll let us get a better idea of what you're doing and how to do it "Reacty" (also, this code doesn't need a that=this rebinding. maybe the full code does, but as is, React will make sure the binds "just work" so you can use `this`)

Comment: Breadcrumb note: I had a continuous build integration tool that was masking improvements / improved effects / further developments of my JSX source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd call myself a complete novice here but looking at this code
https://github.com/abdullin/gtd/blob/master/web/components/TaskComposer.jsx

You should be able to bind to the textareas value:

```
<textarea id="description" 
          value={that.state.text} ...
```

and then you can pull out the value in your click handler like this:

```
var description = this.state.text;
```

Let me know if this works :)

## UPDATE

Just looked at the React home-page (https://facebook.github.io/react/) and the 3rd example **An Application** seems to follow this pattern as well

```
var TodoList = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var createItem = function(itemText, index) {
      return <li key={index + itemText}>{itemText}</li>;
    };
    return <ul>{this.props.items.map(createItem)}</ul>;
  }
});
var TodoApp = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {items: [], text: ''};
  },
  onChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({text: e.target.value});
  },
  handleSubmit: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var nextItems = this.state.items.concat([this.state.text]);
    var nextText = '';
    this.setState({items: nextItems, text: nextText});
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>TODO</h3>
        <TodoList items={this.state.items} />
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.text} />
          <button>{'Add #' + (this.state.items.length + 1)}</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

React.render(<TodoApp />, mountNode);
```

So to answer you're question I think the React way to do stuff is to **bind** to `this.state.`

Answer (score 3):

You should be using the `refs` attribute. 
So lets say you have a render method that looks like *this*:

```
render: function () {
    <MyTextBox ref="myText" />
    <div>Some other element</div>
}
```

Now lets say the rendered `MyTextBox` element has a `expode()` method. You could call it using:

```
this.refs.myText.explode()
```

Essentially, `refs` has a property `myText` on it because during render, you provided a ref name to it by writing `ref="myText"`
You can find more info [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#the-ref-string-attribute)

Comment: Ok so you use the `ref` to gain access to the DOM node `React.findDOMNode(this.refs.myText)` instead of using `id` attribute and `document.getElementById(..)`

Comment: Also, what you're saying here is that if your component renders another component you can call that other components *public* method e.g. from a change handler function - correct me if I'm wrong :)

Comment: ... Ok I understand now :) what you're saying is using `ref` means you can pickup the element in the submit buttons click handler and get the textareas value. This means no need to have change-handler on the textarea element to track its value. Ref makes more sense here...